# Can we get a picture of Oumuamua with Hubble Space Telescope?

Tags: telescope, hubble-telescope, oumuamua

Can we get a picture of [Oumuamua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBOumuamua) with Hubble Space Telescope?
If not, what are the reasons?

Answers why other telescopes might fail to get a picture of Oumuamua are welcomed as well.

Comment: Welcome to astronomy SE! Great question BTW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No we can't, [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBOumuamua) states that:

> the size and shape have not been directly observed as ʻOumuamua appears as nothing more than a point source of light even in the most powerful telescopes

In addition, [note c](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%BBOumuamua#cite_note-23) states that:

> Brightness peaked at 19.7 mag on 18 October 2017, and faded below 27.5 mag (the limit of Hubble Space Telescope for fast-moving objects) around 1 January 2018.

So the HST has a limit of 27.5 magnitude for fast-moving objects, and ʻOumuamua is now fainter than that limit.

Comment: Generating an ephemeris for 1I/'Oumuamua for HST in JPL HORIZONS shows that it is now magnitude 36...